# $el is undefined in my view. Why?

Tags: backbone.js

```
var divElement = Backbone.View.extend({        
        initialize: function () {
            this.render();
        },          
        render: function () {                        
            $el.append("<ul id='ulList'></ul>"),
            wines.each(function (model) {
                $("#ulList").append("<li>" + model.winename + "</li>");
            });
            return this;
        }
    });
```

When I instantiate my view I get $el as undefined... why so? By default el should be a div

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "this":

```
    this.$el.append("<ul id='ulList'></ul>"),
```

see here: http://backbonejs.org/#View-render

Seems append works just as well as html() for this.

Comment: `.append` will put it in the div, just after everything else in there.

Comment: ["The `.append()` method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection"](http://api.jquery.com/append/). @Kyle is right.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with scope, in the scope of your function JS does not know where to find the $el variable, so it thinks it is undefined because no where in the function is it explicitly defined. However, it is defined on the "this" object, so this.$el will return the element. If you write you javascript in something called [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode), small mistakes like this will get picked up automatically.